# Symfony 3.4 Remember me in not working after restart browser

Tags: symfony

I set up a login function with symfony manually without using FOSUserBUndle and i would like to add the option remember me feature

Every thing works well, the cookie is well created except that when I leave the browser and I re-open it  I'm still disconnected

Here is my code :

```
public function connect(array $arrayUser, array $roles)
{

    if (!isset($user['secretKey'])) {
        $credentialsClient = $this->get('custom.security.credentials_client');
        $accessToken       = $credentialsClient->getAccessToken();
        $secretKey         = $credentialsClient->fetch('/security/'.$arrayUser['id']);
    } else {
        $secretKey         = $arrayUser['secretKey'];
    }
    $user = new User();
    $user->setId($arrayUser['id']);
    $user->setRoles($roles);
    $user->setUsername($arrayUser['username']);
    $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();



    if ($request->get('_remember_me') == 'on'){
        //Token to set the REMEMBERME cookie
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'secured_area', $roles);

        //Token to set the session
        $token_session = new CustomToken($user->getId(), $secretKey, $roles);
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token_session);
        $this->get('session')->set('apiUser', serialize($arrayUser));
       $rememberMeService = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices([$arrayUser],$this->getParameter('secret'),'secured_area', [
        'path' => '/',
        'name' => 'REMEMBERME',
        'domain' => 'localhost',
        'secure' => false,
        'httponly' => true,
        'lifetime' => 1209600, // 14 days
        'always_remember_me' => false,
        'remember_me_parameter' => '_remember_me'
      ]);
       $response = new Response();
       $rememberMeService->loginSuccess($request, $response, $token);

       $event   = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
       $response->sendHeaders();
       $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
       return $response;


    }else{
        $token = new CustomToken($user->getId(), $secretKey, $roles);
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
        $this->get('session')->set('apiUser', serialize($arrayUser));

        // Now dispatch the login event

        $event   = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
    }

}
```

Thanks you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I change this part of code like this :

```
 if ($request->get('_remember_me') == 'on'){
    //Token to set the REMEMBERME cookie
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user->getId(), $user->getPassword(), 'secured_area', $roles);


    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    $this->get('session')->set('apiUser', serialize($arrayUser));
   $rememberMeService = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices([$arrayUser],$this->getParameter('secret'),'secured_area', [
    'path' => '/',
    'name' => 'REMEMBERME',
    'domain' => 'localhost',
    'secure' => false,
    'httponly' => true,
    'lifetime' => 1209600, // 14 days
    'always_remember_me' => false,
    'remember_me_parameter' => '_remember_me'
  ]);
```

and i'm a connected when i logged in with the UsernamePasswordToken token but no cookie is set because $user does  not represent UserInterface implementation

And that is my problem , i'm not using FOSUserBundle or an Entity to load user but user is load via API

If i do like this :

```
if ($request->get('_remember_me') == 'on'){
    //Token to set the REMEMBERME cookie
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'secured_area', $roles);


    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    $this->get('session')->set('apiUser', serialize($arrayUser));
   $rememberMeService = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices([$arrayUser],$this->getParameter('secret'),'secured_area', [
    'path' => '/',
    'name' => 'REMEMBERME',
    'domain' => 'localhost',
    'secure' => false,
    'httponly' => true,
    'lifetime' => 1209600, // 14 days
    'always_remember_me' => false,
    'remember_me_parameter' => '_remember_me'
  ]);
```

I get this error : **There is no user provider for user "UserBundle\Model\User".**